# MySQL Server not starting on OSX

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp, mariadb

First I have installed MariaDB on my OSX and then I have installed XAMPP on MY OSX.
Now I can start apache web server but MYSQL server is not starting.

I have a few questions which are listed below?

1. Is it because of MariaDB already installed?
2. Is it a port issue?
3. XAMPP have MariaDB instance so what happened with the older MariaDB instance.

Can someone share their experience with the above questions?

> ANS : Error occurred because 3306 port is already taken. Change the
>   port number and it will work fine.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the mysql log. It could be because both are trying to run on port 3306, but more information will be found in the log.

Comment: @aynber Thanks. i will check

Comment: It's possible that port `3306` already taken.

Comment: @Justinas Right the 3306 port is already taken. I have changed the port and it's working thanks All.